# Display Only Searched Data from Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to search for some data on a database and display it. at the moment my code displays all the data on the database and not just the specific data I have searched for. Any ideas on how to fix this? This is my php code at the moment. I have created a form as well to enter the data.

```
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,"Animal_Tracker");

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use test_db : " . mysqli_error($link));
  }

$sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations ");

if ($sql == FALSE)
{
  die($sql." Error on query: ".mysqli_error($link)); 
}

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo $result ['Animal Type'];
echo " ";
echo $result ['Latitude'];
echo "<br> ";
echo $result ['Longitude'];
echo " <br>";
echo $result ['Seen'];
echo " <br> ";
echo $result ['Time'];
echo "<br> ";
echo "<br> ";
}
```

Comment: your query does  not look like searching anything. What u are looking to search ?

Comment: *I have created a form as well to enter the data.* Post the code of your form. Also what part are you stuck with sql, php, html, all of them?

Comment: This is so incredibly basic. Read up on MySQL's `WHERE`.

Comment: <h2> Search </h2>
<form action = "search.php" method = "post" >
  Search for: <input type = "text" name ="find" /> in
  <select NAME = "field">
    <Option VALUE = "Animal Type"> Animal Type</option>
    <Option VALUE = "latitude"> Latitude</option>
    <Option VALUE = "longitude"> longitude</option>
    <Option VALUE = "dateseen"> Date Required</option>
    <Option VALUE = "timeseen"> Time</option>
  </Select>

Comment: Are you trying to display the whole table but only specific columns? Can you be more specific about what exactly do you want?

Comment: Basically there are 5 columns. User should be able to search data in either animal type, latitude, longitude, dataseen or time seen. If for example user searches for a 'Dog' then all information about the dog should be displayed. i.e animal type, latitude, longitude, date seen and time seen.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 $sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations ");
```

to something like

```
 $sql=mysqli_query($link, "Select * FROM Locations WHERE Latitude < 50");
```

so you would only display locations with latitude smaller 50 ... same goes for animal type etc ... its called SQL WHERE syntax

Comment: This works if i hard code it. But I want it to be possible to search any criteria the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fetch_assoc

```
$sql = "select * from Locations ";
$result = $db_selected -> query($sql);

while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
echo $fila['Animal Type']
}
```

but, with mysqi_fetch_array() this is the syntax

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row)
{
echo $row['Animal type'];
}
```

see more information [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)